# How to hide the current method from exception stack trace in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'd like to know if there is a way to throw an exception from inside a method, but to not include that method in the exception stack trace.  E.g.

```
void ThrowSomeException()
{
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

And then, if I call that method from a method called `Foo()` I want the exception stack trace to start with `at Foo()`, not `at ThrowSomeException()`.  I assume if this was possible it might be through the use of attributes on the method.

I'm interested in the general answer, but in case this isn't possible, what I'm really trying to do is create an extension method `AssertEqual()` for `IEnumerable` that I'll use in NUnit tests.  So when I call `myEnumerable.AssertEqual(otherEnumerable)` and it fails, NUnit should report the error inside the test method, not inside the extension method.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the CollectionAssert helpers?  NUnit 2.4+; it sounds like you're after AreEqual or AreEquivalent.

Comment: Ah thank you -- I'm new to NUnit.  I'm still interested in the answer to the first question though, if anyone knows.

Comment: +1 because you asked a kind of crazy question but explained why. I can not tell you how much it bugs me to see a crazy question and wonder why anyone would ever want what was being asked. Good Job!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is now built-in starting with .NET 6 using the StackTraceHiddenAttribute

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktracehiddenattribute?view=net-6.0

```cs
[StackTraceHidden]
void ThrowSomeException()
{
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to make it work for async methods?

Answer (score 23):

Using the code at the end of this answer allows you to write code such as:

```
[HideFromStackTrace] // apply this to all methods you want omitted in stack traces
static void ThrowIfNull(object arg, string paramName)
{
    if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
}

static void Foo(object something)
{
    ThrowIfNull(something, nameof(something));
    …
}

static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Foo(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.GetStackTraceWithoutHiddenMethods());
    }                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}                      // gets a stack trace string representation
                       // that excludes all marked methods
```

Here's one possible implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited=false)]
public class HideFromStackTraceAttribute : Attribute { }

public static class MethodBaseExtensions
{
    public static bool ShouldHideFromStackTrace(this MethodBase method)
    {
        return method.IsDefined(typeof(HideFromStackTraceAttribute), true);
    }
}

public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static string GetStackTraceWithoutHiddenMethods(this Exception e)
    {
        return string.Concat(
            new StackTrace(e, true)
                .GetFrames()
                .Where(frame => !frame.GetMethod().ShouldHideFromStackTrace())
                .Select(frame => new StackTrace(frame).ToString())
                .ToArray());  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^
    }                         // required because you want the usual stack trace
}                             // formatting; StackFrame.ToString() formats differently
```

Note that this only causes marked methods to be excluded from one particular *representation of* the stack trace, not from the stack trace *itself*. I know of no way to achieve the latter.

**P.S.:** If all you want is to hide a method in the *Call Stack* window during a debugging session, simply apply the [`[DebuggerHidden]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) to the method.

Comment: Best solution so far. And Expandable because you can add additional data to the attributes and enable a expanded formatting. Also you can define some precompiler conditions in the attribute to support different debug modes or do it with a static class. ( Release, Customer_Test, Test, Test_Full, ... ).

Comment: I voted for Paolo's solution (since it can be used in cases where you can't modify code with a new attribute), but this is still a cool solution too!

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you could derive your own exception type and override the `StackTrace` property getter to exclude your method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MyException : Exception {

    string _excludeFromStackTrace;

    public MyException(string excludeFromStackTrace) {
        _excludeFromStackTrace = excludeFromStackTrace;
    }

    public override string StackTrace {
        get {
            List<string> stackTrace = new List<string>();
            stackTrace.AddRange(base.StackTrace.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None));
            stackTrace.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(_excludeFromStackTrace));
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, stackTrace.ToArray());
        }
    }
}

class Program {

    static void TestExc() {
        throw new MyException("Program.TestExc");
    }

    static void foo() {
        TestExc();
    }

    static void Main(params string[] args) {
        try{
            foo();
        } catch (Exception exc){
            Console.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm seems a little bit clumsy but my feeling is now that this might be the only way to do it, so I'll mark it as the answer, thank you.

Comment: Alternative approach to the stack trace string/array fiddling: Make use of the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class instead: `new StackTrace(someException, skipFrames: …).ToString()`. (However, be aware that `StackTrace.ToString()` doesn't by default emit file names and line numbers, so one would have to derive these from the `StackFrame` objects that can be derived from a `StackTrace`.)

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that you want to do this in order to consolidate code that is used to create the exception?  
 In that case, rather than write a `ThrowException()` function, why not write a `GetException()` function?  Then in Foo, just do `throw GetException();`

Comment: Not entirely true in this specific case, but good idea otherwise, thanks

Comment: Isn't working when wanting something like `if (Disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException()`.

Answer (score 3):

The GetStackTraceWithoutHiddenMethods() extension method answer is fine, except that Exception.ToString() doesn't use the StackTrace property, it calls GetStackTrace() instead, which isn't overrridable. So, if one wishes to use this extension method with their own Exception based types, they have to override ToString() rather than overriding the StackTrace property.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps in a near futur, you could use [StackTraceHidden]. For now, System.Diagnostics.StackTraceHiddenAttribute is internal but [Consider exposing `System.Diagnostics.StackTraceHiddenAttribute` publicly](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37985) is on the go.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that this is an improvement to the existing answers.**

---

The [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973896/4390133) of this question is really clumsy because

1. It determines the method that we need to hide from stack trace by its name using pure string.
2. Splitting the stack trace is based on the `string.Split` method.
3. It hides just one method from `StackTrace` property, No more.

But it overrides `StackTrace` property itself (which the desired behavior of the question)

---

The [Most Upvoted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898531/4390133) is really cleaner because

1. it is using an attribute instead of specifying the name of the method as a string.
2. It could be used to hide more than one method from the `StackTrace`.

but it really complicated and adding two more classes just
for extension methods.
And the most important weak point in it is not overriding
the `StackTrace` property itself.

---

After reading the previous two solutions, I think I reached to the simplest AND most clean way (which combine the best of the two top answer to this question)

here is the infrastructure that needed.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class StackTraceHiddenAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class SomeException : Exception
{
    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat(
                new StackTrace(this, true)
                    .GetFrames()
                    .Where(frame => !frame.GetMethod().IsDefined(typeof(StackTraceHiddenAttribute), true))
                    .Select(frame => new StackTrace(frame).ToString())
                    .ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is an example of using the previous infrastructure

```
[StackTraceHidden] // apply this to all methods you want to be omitted in stack traces
static void Throw()
{
    throw new SomeException();
}

static void Foo()
{
    Throw();
}

static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Foo();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }                  
}
```

**EDIT**
According to a comment by @Stakx on this answer, *which is deleted immediately after putting it*, he points out to some important idea:

 This solution works only for the custom defined exceptions, and his solution working on all exceptions types, which is absolutely correct. 
According to that, here is one extension method, without much more complex, which could solve the problem and work on all the exception types.

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static string GetStackTraceWithoutHiddenMethods(this Exception e)
    {
        return string.Concat(
           new StackTrace(e, true)
               .GetFrames()
               .Where(frame => !frame.GetMethod().IsDefined(typeof(StackTraceHiddenAttribute), true))
               .Select(frame => new StackTrace(frame).ToString())
               .ToArray());
    }                         
}
```

which is almost identical to his code, except integrating the `IsDefined` method.

Comment: This basic idea worked well for me. I have a bunch of unit test helper classes that I want to hide from the unit test runner. The only change I made is I already had [DebuggerHidden] on all of them, so I just filtered for that attribute instead of a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension method according with the [StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) solution and worked perfectly.

```cs
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    [DebuggerHidden]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Throw(this Exception exception) => throw exception;
}
```

and then we can use it...

```
using static SomeNamespace.ExceptionExtensions;

public class SomeClass
{
    private void SomeMethod(string value)
    {
        var exception = GetArgumentException(nameof(value), value);
        exception?.Throw(); // only throw if any exception was getted

        ... //method implementation
    }

    private Exception GetArgumentException(string paramName, string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new ArgumentNullException(paramName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return new ArgumentException("value is empty.", paramName);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**With that the `Throw()` method will not appear in the stack trace.**

Answer (score 0):

If you tell the compiler to aggressively inline your method, it should prevent your method from ever making it to the call stack in the first place:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void ThrowSomeException()
{
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

This attribute is available as of .NET 4.5.

However, this is only considered a *strong hint* to the compiler, and in some cases it still doesn't cause inlining. For example, I don't think it can inline it if you call the method from a different assembly, or if you compile in debug mode.

One workaround for this could be to only *create* the exception with your helper, and *throw* it from the calling code.

```
public static InvalidOperationException InvalidOperation(FormattableString message)
{
  return new InvalidOperationException(FormattableString.Invariant(message));
}

// calling code
throw ExceptionHelpers.InvalidOperation($"{0} is not a valid value", value);
```

But if your helper method has logic to determine *whether* to throw the exception, that might not work out for you:

```
public static class Require
{
    [ContractAnnotation("condition:false => halt")]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public static void True(bool condition)
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            throw ExceptionHelpers.InvalidOperation($"Expected condition was not met.");
        }
    }
}
```

In those cases, you'll probably have to muck with the exception stack traces as the other answers here show. For example, you may want to ignore methods marked with the `DebuggerHiddenAttribute`.