# How can I tell the compiler to ignore a method in stack traces?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

Are there any attributes I can apply to boilerplate methods so that such methods do not appear in stack traces?  I've got a lot of them and in some cases they are several levels deep.  It's just cluttering things.

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void ThrowMe()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static void HideMe()
    {
        ThrowMe();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            HideMe();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This throws this stack trace:

> at Spork.Program.ThrowMe() in C:\Projects\XXX\Testing Sandbox\ConsoleTesting\Program.cs:line 58
>
> **at Spork.Program.HideMe() in C:\Projects\XXX\Testing Sandbox\ConsoleTesting**\Program.cs:line 64
>
> at Spork.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\XXX\Testing Sandbox\ConsoleTesting\Program.cs:line 70

Comment: What you're asking for is something that's convenient in some cases and a nightmare in others. Imagine someone else was reading your stack trace and saw that `Main` called `ThrowMe()`. Then they investigate `Main` but can't see where that call is made. Also, imagine `Main` is 500 lines long so its not as obvious as your sample. I sympathize with you but ultimately this "feature" would get abused and coding would be a nightmare, that's why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the current method from exception stack trace in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973343/how-to-hide-the-current-method-from-exception-stack-trace-in-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put Console.WriteLine(e) in the catch block.  Switch to the release build and press Ctrl+F5.  You'll see this:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.ThrowMe() in C:\Users\hpassant\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 9
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\hpassant\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 17
```

Note that the HideMe() method is *not* visible in the stack trace.  Mission accomplished.

The method call was not shown in the trace because *the JIT optimizer inlined the method*: this is the only way to hide methods in the stack trace.

It is not something you can control well, the method has to be 'small' and not throw any exception itself.  This is otherwise normally considered a problem, not a feature.  Hard to figure out how to code got from A to B.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx)

Comment: That prevents the debugger from breaking on caught exceptions in that member, but does that affect the stack trace?

Comment: It turns out this answer was correct.  Hans spells it out in further detail.

Comment: This attribute is works wonderfully for hiding wrapper methods from the debugger. They do not appear in the callstack, stepping into one will instead take you to the next call below it, which is what you wanted to see anyway not the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If your method isn't simple enough to get inlined automatically, you can give the compiler a strong hint that you want it to be with the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute.

You still have to compile in release mode.