# Class and properties attributes

Tags: c#, winforms

i just download a starter project for learning purpose.
in this i found some tags on class as well as on properties. Can some one shade light of these? like why we use them ?

```
[Serializable]
    public partial class RoleToPermission
    {
        [DataMember]
        [ColumnAttribute(DbType = "int")]
        [AddEditDelete(Ignore=true)]
        public int RolePermissionID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [ColumnAttribute(DbType = "int")]
        [AddEditDelete(Add = false, Delete = true)]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
```

Comment: these are called Attributes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664611%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are used to attach *additional* information onto program entities, such as a class, a property, a field or a method. At run-time, the interested code can retrieve this information using reflection.

For instance, when you use a `DataContractSerializer` to serialize an object, the serializer will look for any field or property that is tagged with a `[DataMember]` attribute. So the `[DataMember]` attribute allows you to *declare* which fields and properties should be serialized.

There exists some [useful attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144833/most-useful-attributes), and you can also [write your own attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for other purposes.